# How can I avoid if/else inside the notification of an observable?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have an observable (from observer/observable pattern) that has a list of listeners registered.
When an event happens the notification code does:

```
if(event == TYPE_A){  
  for(Listener l:listeners){  
       l.fireEventA();  
  }  
else if(event == TYPE_B){  
  for(Listener l:listeners){  
       l.fireEventB();  
  }  
if(event == TYPE_C){  
  for(Listener l:listeners){  
       l.fireEventC();  
  }
```

I was wondering is this the best I can do or should I avoid the `if-else` in the notification? How could I improve this?

Comment: `switch`? Or what were you thinking of?

Comment: @nfechner:Not `switch`.Perhaps the observable should be "broken"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about refactoring your solution so that you push the responsibiliy of whether or not to fire to the listener:

class Listener {
       private EventType eventType;

```
   public Listener(EventType eventType) {
       this.eventType = eventType;
   }

   public void fireEvent(EventType eventType) {
       if(this.eventType == eventType) {
          ...do stuff
       }
   }
```

Then the client code looks like this:

```
..setup...
listeners.add(new Listener(TYPE_A);
listeners.add(new Listener(TYPE_B);
..and so on
```

Then when you need to fire an event:

```
for(Listener l:listeners){  
   l.fireEvent(event);  
}
```

Is this an option for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can prepare a Map with key as event type and value as list of listeners, like thisL

```
Map<EventType,List<Listener>> eventListenerMap;
```

Then look for the listener list using event type key and fire corresponding listeners

Comment: Interesting,but this means that each listener must implement 3 interfaces, right?So it complicates things for the client side (observers).

Comment: Only one additional with some `fireEvent` method

Comment: Irrespective of number of events you have, you make each listener implement an interface `IListener`. This interface will have a `fireEvent` method. Each listener will write the event specific listener code in this method.